# Integrating a Podio webform into a react app?

Tags: reactjs, podio

I have created a react app in which I have created a website, I also have a podio form that needs to be embedded into my enquire page. I cannot fathom how to use the embed code that Podio provides, and get the for to display on my enquire page. The best I can get is that it provides a link to my podio account and not the webform. Any help would be great.

From a video it was suggested that I add the link to my component, this however did not work, it just gives me a link to my podio account

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.